# Firebase rewrites in single page VueJS app in subfolder

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting

## Background

I have a site that is structured like this:

```
root
  — /public
    — index.html <— landing page
    — 404.html
    — /library 
      — index.html <— single page VueJS app
```

The single page app is found here: https://uxtools-3ac6e.firebaseapp.com/library/

Here's my firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/library/*",
        "destination": "/library/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## The Problem

When the app begins to route to sub paths, like https://uxtools-3ac6e.firebaseapp.com/library/lists/order-group-best-sources-learn-ux, a refresh will redirect to 404 instead of library/index.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a double-star glob to match:

```
"source": "/library/**"
```

The single-star will only match up to a slash, so it would match `/library/lists` but not `/library/lists/foo`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. If anyone else is facing this problem, the rewrite was also changing the relatives paths to my javascript and images. Absolute paths fixed this.